# c++ textfile borland

Tags: c++, file-io

I ask about the function that seek in the K-th line in a text file and the one that read the text file by line or by character in C++! knowing that i'm working with borland.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: It would help to know more clearly what you're asking about.  There are standard functions to read a character in a file, or a line in a text file.  There are no standard functions to find the Kth line in a text file.  Are you asking how to write one?  Is this homework?

Comment: ok thank you! but could you tell me how to deal with pointer in a text file to extract information?

Comment: @David: No my work is about extracting information from a text file seperated by " " and is it possible to deal with pointer to do that?

Answer (score 1):

[**fpeek**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fpeek/) is an open source application that does exactly that. Check the sources and see how its done.

I took a quick look and I believe you'll end up with something like this (I haven't tested this code):

```
std::ifstream file(filename);

std::string line;
int pos = 1; 
while (std::getline(file, line))
{   
    // Find if current line should be displayed
    if (15 == pos) // looking for the 15th line in the file
    {   
        std::cout << pos << ": " << line << std::endl;
    }   

    pos++;
}
```

Comment: what's the index of the first line in a text file? it begins from 0 or 1?

Comment: std::getline() begins reading from the first line of in file.

Comment: @karlphillip : could you tell me pleaze about std:: and its functionalities! I'm applying it without underestanding its sense// thank U

Comment: `std::` refers to the standard namespace. If your application states `using namespace std;` in the beginning then you don't need to add `std::` in front of the STL functions/data types.

Comment: ok how we can extract inf from a text file using pointer?

Comment: This is not a chat, @samia. This is a Q&A forum. You asked a question and I answered it. I even gave you code to illustrate what you need to do. If you have another question feel free to ask it in another thread. Just don't forget to accept my answer, there's a little check box near every answer and you can click on it to select it as the official answer to your question.

Comment: @karlphillip: I'm so sorry just becoz i'm a new member in this group and i seek for more information becoz the idea is not clear fo me!Execuse me

Comment: No problem. I suggest you read our FAQ when you have the time: http://stackoverflow.com/faq